# powershell copy a string in one file to another

Tags: xml, powershell

I wanted to copy the `uid` value from one file to another.

If test1.xml contains `something something uid="123"` and test2.xml contains `something something uid="11111"`

test2.xml should then be `something something uid="123"`

How can I do this?

Comment: Google how you can read an xml file and then use .selectnode to find your UID. If you have problems with the code than add the code to the question and we will try to help you

Answer (score 0):

i found something like this, but i dont understand need of two input files. First input is original, second text to be inserted and third is output, but this is not whole thing i need.

```
$inputFile1 = "C:\ephemeral\file1.xml"

$inputFile2 = "C:\ephemeral\file2.xml"

$outputFile = "C:\ephemeral\file3.txt"

if ((Select-String -Pattern "uid=" -Path $inputFile1 |
select -last 1) -match ":(/>\d+):")
{
$insertPoint = $Matches[1]

Get-Content -Path $inputFile1 | select -First $insertPoint | Out-File $outputFile
Get-Content -Path $inputFile2 | Out-File $outputFile -Append
Get-Content -Path $inputFile1 | select -Skip $insertPoint | Out-File $outputFile -Append
}
```